# Random Tree in Racket

Tags: algorithm, tree, code-generation, racket

I am trying to create a random tree from lists in Racket.

The tree is made from a list of operators and a list of terminals.

The output will look like this:

```
'(* (+ 2 4) 2)
```

So the list can be called with the eval function.

Further there should be a maximum level specified.

So my guess is the procedure will look like the following.

```
(define (make-tree tree level) ... )
```

I thought about using the `map` function and expanding each level at depth, but I'm new to lisp-likes so I'm finding it hard to figure the algorithm I need.

At the moment each operator only takes two parameters (essentially the generated trees are binary trees), but it would be useful to include in any answer how to expand the function to enable three or more parameters.

Comment: Racket and lisp aren't the same. Further your question isn't clear to me, could you elaborate it a bit more ? For example, which tree does `'(* (+ (2 4) 2))` represent ?

Comment: My apologies, I should have said lisp-like, it represents * being the root, which contains the nodes (+ 2 4) and 2

Comment: If `*` is the root and has 2 children, `(+ 2 4)` and `2`, shouldn't it be `'(* (+ 2 4) 2)` ?

Comment: Yes it should, I will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(define (random-from-list xs)
  (list-ref xs (random (length xs))))

;; A TERMINAL is one if terminal1, terminal2, ...

(define TERMINALS '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(define (random-terminal)
  (random-from-list TERMINALS))

;; An OPERATOR is one of '+ '-, '* '/ .

(define OPERATORS '(+ - * /))

(define (random-operator)
  (random-from-list OPERATORS))

;; A TREE is either
;;      i) a terminal
;; or  ii) (list operator terminal1 terminal2 ... terminalN)

(define (random-tree . ignore)
  (match (random 5)               
    [0 (random-list-tree)]      ; probability 1/5 = 20%
    [_ (random-terminal)]))

(define (random-list-tree)
  (define N (+ 2 (random (+ 3 1)))) ; at least two operands, at most 2+3
  (cons (random-operator) (build-list N random-tree)))
```

To generate trees of a specific depth:

```
1. generate a tree T
2. find the depth D of T
3. if the depth D is of the desired depth return T
4. otherwise go to 1.
```

Comment: Is the way you suggest a specific depth a brute force approach?

Comment: No. "Brute force" implies that one computes all possibilities until a solution is found. Here we just compute random possibilities - not all.

Comment: Thanks for this btw :)

Comment: What does the `. ignore` part mean?

Comment: @HedgepigMatt The `.` stands for an optional number of arguments. So `. ignore` will put all arguments in the list `ignore`.

Comment: The function `build-list` needs a function of one argument. I want to use `build-list` with `random-tree` so I made `random-tree` ignore any arguments it is given.